# Any difference in meaning? "Until what time" and "How late"

Tags: phrase-usage

To me, **"until what time"** and **"how late"** seem to have the same exact meaning and can be used interchangeably.  For example, the following pairs of sentences illustrate some usages that seem the same to me:

- a1) **Until what time** were you at work last night?
  a2) **How late** were you at work last night?
- b1) **Until what time** did you stay at work last night?
  b2) **How late** did you stay at work last night?
- c1) **Until what time** did you work last night?
  c2) **How late** did you work last night?
- d1) **Until what time** can I call you?
  d2) **How late** can I call you?

Am I correct that these phrases are exactly the same?  If not, why?

Comment: Although you can front ***until what time***, it'd be more usual to front only ***what time*** and leave ***until*** stranded: "**What time** did you work **until** last night?"

Comment: D1 isn't quite as good as A1-C1 because the duration of ***calling*** is very short, and you wouldn't "call someone until 8PM", for example.  In contrast, ***being at work, staying at work,*** and ***working*** can stretch on for hours and hours.

Comment: Anyway you don't mean D1 is incorrect; am I right?
Meanwhile how would bee better if I want to rephrase D1 (if it needs to be rewritten)?

Comment: I don't mean that it's incorrect.  It can be interpreted in a way that makes sense.  I wouldn't say it, though.  D2 is fine and natural.

Comment: Thank you @snailplane. But do you confirm my idea? I guess they all mean exactly the same thing, but the only difference between the sentences of each group is their formality level. Right? :)

Comment: I have edited/rephrased this question to focus on the phrase usage rather than the example sentence pairs.  I believe this essentially captures the original question and hopefully can get this reopened.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing specifically wrong with any of those examples.  There are three notable differences between using "until" vs. "how late":

1. Until is more formal and is soliciting a specific time, such as 3AM.
2. "How late" is less formal and an estimate is appropriate, such as 'sometime after 3'.
3. In these examples, "until" is not relative to anything.  "How late" suggests someone was either working past their normal time or late at night.

Comment: Thank you @boatseller. But you didn't confirm! Are they identical in meaning? I think the answer is 'yes', but the only difference is the formality level of each one as you mentioned. Am I right?  :)

Comment: There are these three differences, at least, so no, they are not identical.

Comment: Just by saying: ("How late" suggests someone was either working past their normal time or late at night.) did you mean less than their normal working hours or more than their working hours?

Comment: Past their normal quitting time, which suggests overtime, but not necessarily.